# abort spawned program when it prints a specific warning

Tags: linux, bash, kill, exec, wait

My Bash 4 script calls a third-party program `P` (one that I can't recompile), which prints warnings to STDOUT.  When it prints `yikes`, it also enters an infinite loop.  So when I detect a `yikes`, how can I immediately stop `P` and return control to my script?  (And let `P` finish normally otherwise.)

Possibly useful fragments:

`(echo $BASHPID > /tmp/subpid; ./P | tee /tmp/Pout ) &`

`tail -f /tmp/Pout | grep -m1 yikes && kill -9 $(cat /tmp/subpid)`

`wait`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`expect`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect):

```
P | { expect -c 'expect -timeout -1 yikes' && killall P ; }
```

This usage may not be optimal, still `expect` is the right tool for the job.

If `P` prints more after `yikes` then it will notice the broken pipe, so the `killall` isn't needed:

```
P | expect -c 'expect -timeout -1 yikes'
```

Comment: Recent Ubuntus don't include it by default. `sudo apt-get install expect`?

Comment: In my case, after yikes, P prints an *infinite* number of lines!

Answer (score 1):

```
coproc ./P
grep -q -m1 yikes <&${COPROC[0]} && [[ $COPROC_PID ]] && kill -9 $COPROC_PID
```

Demo:

```
coproc { sleep 1; echo yikes; sleep 2; }; grep -q -m1 yikes <&${COPROC[0]} && [[ $COPROC_PID ]] && kill -9 $COPROC_PID
coproc { sleep 1; echo zzzzz; sleep 2; }; grep -q -m1 yikes <&${COPROC[0]} && [[ $COPROC_PID ]] && kill -9 $COPROC_PID
```

Found from https://stackoverflow.com/a/26779617/2097284.

However, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86270/how-do-you-use-the-command-coproc-in-bash explains why named pipes are better (although deadlock isn't possible here), and why `expect` is better yet.